# Regex expression: file names that do not contain a word and matches a given pattern

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I need a regex expression to check whether a file name matches the following pattern: 
`report*.txt` and does not contain the following string "`car`".
So for `report_car_as.txt`, `rep_as`, `report_tds`, it should ***return false***, and for `report_abc.txt`, `report_sa.txt` it should ***return true***.

I have the following code lines:

```
final File f = new File("~/home/report_fds.txt");
final String regex1 = "^((?!car).)*$";
final String regex2 = "report.*\\.txt";
System.out.println(f.getName().matches(regex2));
```

I dont know how to combine those 2 regex expressions. Can you help me, please?

Note: I am not allowed to use an if statement like

```
 if(a.matches(regex1) && a.matches(regex2));
```

Comment: Perhaps, [`^(?!.*car).*report[^/]*\.txt$`](https://regex101.com/r/lL0nE9/1). Or `^.*(?!.*car)report[^/]*\.txt$`. It depends on where `car` should be disallowed. Or something like `^~(?:/[^/]*)*(?!.*car)report[^/]*\.txt$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your requirements, you can use this regex `^report((?!.*car).*)\.txt$`, where:

`^report` means, that your file name begins with report word

`\.txt$` your file name ends with the .txt

`((?!.*car).*)` is content between the `report` and `.txt`, which contains any characters, except `car` sequence (`?!` is negative lookahead).

If the `car` word could be not just between the `report` and `txt`, you can specify it by adding the `(?!.*car).*` to the regex beginning, like `^(?!.*car).*report((?!.*car).*)\.txt$`